# change popup to redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and add digits plugin for customers to login via phone, in my wordpress site theme have a modal pop sign up form via email.

this is the code used to call popup:

```html
              <?php if(negarshop_option('header_res_user') == "true" and function_exists('WC')):
                $account_link = wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' );
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $account_link; ?>"<?php if (!$current_user->exists()) { ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-popup-modal"<?php }?> class="rh-item"><i class="fal fa-user"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

i want to instead of opening a modal popup it redirect to mysite.com/my-account/
or
use digits modal shortcode [dm-modal] instead of the theme default popup.

can someone help me change the source code please?

Comment: Does removing `<?php if (!$current_user->exists()) { ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-popup-modal"<?php }?>` not work for you? `$account_link = 'mysite.com/my-account/';`, yes?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i tried "Definitely not Rafal" suggestion and remove if part but it crash and return error 500.

Comment: @Definitely not Rafal suggestion works perfectly fine i remove another end if it caused the crash. thanks for your help